# In Early Modern English, are there examples of the "a- + gerund" progressive construction where the gerund begins with a vowel?

Tags: grammar, early-modern-english

In Early Modern English, a progressive tense was sometimes constructed as in the example "I was a-hunting". But what happens if the verb begins with a vowel rather than a consonant? Would they say, "I was a-eating", or "I was an-eating", or would they simply have had no way to do this?

Comment: A vowel or a vowel **sound**?

Comment: @Laurel Okay, I guess I mean a vowel sound.

Comment: These  examples aren't gerunds (which were rarely used until after "Victorian" English anyway).

Comment: "Early" Modern English? This construction is current in Kentucky.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, sometimes, at least through the 1700s. After that, not so much. Up through the 1700s in particular it sometimes showed up written *an* before a word with a vowel or *h-*. The OED provides one such citation of ***went an eeling*** here:

> 1780   in *Narragansett Hist. Reg.* (1882) Oct. 104   Went an eeling.

Remember that this is “really”, or originally, the **preposition(!)** *a* combined with a gerund. It was not a prefix! It was only in later years it came to be written as *a-*, although it moved on from *on* to *a/an* fairly early.

In particular, the OED gives:

> ## *a* prep.
>
> **Origin**: A variant or alteration of another lexical item. Etymon: *on* prep.
> **Etymology**: Variant of *on* prep. with loss of the final consonant *-n*, reflecting an unstressed pronunciation of the word in proclitic use; compare *an*, variant of *on* prep., and also *o*, variant of *on* prep. Compare *a-* prefix3, *away* adv., *aright* adv.
>
> [...]
>
> **II**. With a verbal noun or gerund, forming part of a verbal expression. (Now usually written with a hyphen or as one word with the verbal noun.)
>
> 11. Expressing action, with a verbal noun or gerund taken actively. Now archaic and regional.

One of the earlier citations of its use with a gerund is Laȝamon’s *Brut*:

> Wreoð nu wel þene king, þat he ligge a swæting.

Which meant something like "Wrap now well the king, that he lie a sweating."

So it didn’t derive from *one* the way the article *a/an* did. Rather, it was originally the preposition *on*, and its *a* and *an* forms spelling variants of that original. It never meant *one* the way the article did. The OED notes:

> The loss of final *-n* in this word occurs early in terms of the developments described at N n. and perhaps began in fixed idioms where the word was felt to be almost a prefix; compare the parallel development represented by *a-* prefix3. A following consonant favoured the loss of final *-n* (compare discussion at N n.) and so until the 17th cent. the word was often found in complementary distribution with *an* , variant of *on* prep., which was common before vowels (with variation between the two before following *h-* ).
>
> The separate preposition *a* ceased to be used in standard English after about 1700, being replaced by the full *on* , *in* , or the various prepositions which represent them in modern idiom, surviving only in a few set uses from branch II., such as to go a begging , to set a going (occasionally, before a vowel or *h-* , in form *an*, after *an*, prevocalic variant of *a* adj.; compare quots. 1759, 1780 at sense 11b), and in temporal distributive phrases, as *twice a day , once a year* , where it had been early identified with the indefinite article (see a adj. 4). It also survived in a large number of combinations, where it was treated as a prefix to the governed word, and the whole as a compound adverb. Cross-references are given below to a selection of these (see senses 2, 3, 5, 6, 9). Compare *a-* prefix3.

## Yet another *a-* prefix

English has many prefixes that are now written *a-* but which are of completely distinct origins. Just to name an easy one, think of the classically derived privative or negating prefix *a-, an-* seen in *acyclic, asymmetric, atomic, apathy, analphabetic, anarchy, anaesthesia*.

A comment asked whether this *a-* prefix before a gerund isn’t the same *a-* prefix we got from *ge-*. It is not. The Old English *ge-* prefix from common Germanic, still overt in the Middle English hymn [*Adam Lay Ybounden*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_lay_ybounden), today survives only:

1. hidden as *a-, e-, y-, i-* in words like *afford, alike, among, enough, handiwork* (< OE *hand geweorc*), some of which actually came to us via Old Norse not Old English;
2. in deliberate archaïcisms like *ybent, ybound, ybrought, yclad, yclept, ydight, ydrad, ypent, ypight, ywrought*; and
3. in certain rural dialects of England found within a triangle whose three corners are Worcestershire, Surrey, and Cornwall, as well as in Pembrokeshire and Wexford, where it is said that you may yet chance upon such country relics as *ameäde* (made), *azet* (set), *adood* (done).

Comment: Huh. I was sure I'd read (not sure where, now) that *a-* was the modern English descendant of Old English *ge-*. Either that was plain incorrect, or it's more complicated than that!

Comment: @TimPederick The Old English *ge-* prefix from common Germanic today survives only hidden as *a-, e-, y-, i-* in words like *afford, alike, among, enough, handiwork*; in deliberate archaïcisms like *ybent, ybound, ybrought, yclad, yclept, ydight, ydrad, ypent, ypight, ywrought*; and in certain rural dialects of Worcestershire, Surrey, Cornwall, Pembrokeshire, and Wexford, where it is said you may yet chance upon such relics as *ameäde* (made), *azet* (set), *adood* (done). It’s still overt in the Middle English hymn [*Adam Lay Ybounden*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_lay_ybounden).

Answer (score 13):

My regional Appalachian English dialect, famous for retention of EME features, still regularly uses a-gerunding syntax.  We do not ever prefix an- so if it was historically done, it was gone before the language acquisition period of my grandparents, and thus very likely my great-grandparents' and probably great-great grandparents', which makes it extinct by the early-mid 19th century at latest.

It is notable that not only is the first syllable of the verb part very stressed, the "a" is also pronounced as a very stressed schwa (can you stress a schwa?), so more like "uh" than an "ay," or "ah," so it's a bit less awkward to say than you might imagine when it precedes a vowel.  "A eating," admittedly very rare, sounds more like "UH-(y)EET-un," with just the barest hint of an intrusive y.

The dialect is also famous for intrusive consonants. The letter m is often "ilm" for example.

Answer (score 9):

In Early English Books Online, an early modern English corpus, there is one result for *a-eating*, from the 1669 book *[The voyages and travells of the ambassadors sent by Frederick, Duke of Holstein, to the Great Duke of Muscovy and the King of Persia](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A53322.0001.001/1:8.2?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=a-eating)* by Adam Olearius:

> We were told also that a Bear, finding a Vessel of Herrings, which a Peasant had laid down at an Alehouse door, fell *a-eating* of them, and went thence into the Stable, whither the Peasants follow'd him; but having wounded some of them, the rest were glad to get away.

In comparison, there are 20 results for *a-hunting*. *an-* in early modern English would be unexpected.

Based on the modern function of a-prefixing, as described in *[Yale Grammatical Diversity Project](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/a-prefixing)*, the first syllable is almost always stressed in an *a-prefixing* formation. So *a-HUNTing* or *a-EATing* would work, but *a-proDUCing* wouldn't. (I can attest to this with my personal experience in Appalachian English.) That may be why *a-EATing* could be found in early modern English but, say, *a-exTENDing* wouldn't; it would feel redundant to say two separate unstressed vowels in a row.